# Meteor update failed download on windows

Tags: windows, meteor

im getting this error when im trying to update Meteor on windows.
Using git bash here, but getting the same error in command prompt.

Does the file simply not excist, or what is going on here, have had it for some days now, so im just curious if the file excist at all, since its not really officially supported on windows yet?

```
$ meteor update
New version available: 0.3.8
Failed to download: https://d3sqy0vbqsdhku.cloudfront.net/meteor-package-Windows
_NT-i686-0.3.8.tar.gz
```

Comment: I have changed that to return a message informing where to look for an update.

Answer (score 3):

It is not supported officially yet on Windows. You need to rely on weekly checking [win.meteor.com](http://win.meteor.com) for updates.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are correct in your assumption of it not really being officially supported on windows. I also get this same error and have tried everything to get around it. I tried scouring for this package manually and was unable to find it.